# Microphone not working with Google Hangout

Tags: microphone, google-talk

My microphone works very well, except in Google Hangout. I can hear people very well but they don't hear me, or they hear me as if my microphone is constantly muting and unmuting. People have suggested my poor internet connection could be the problem, but without changing my connection I would like to do something else to fix the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. A tip for improving your question and the quality of the answer(s) you receive; read the [FAQ] and [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask). Details are important to get specific answers accurate to your question. You can click [edit] below your questions to add additional information.

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @molavec, you probably won't get an answer.  This is a 3+ yr old question and the OP hasn't been back to the site since posting it.

Answer (score 39):

this worked for me:

> I had to manually rest the audio daemon on my computer.  I have a
>   macbook air though so it might be different for you?
>
> (1)  Type in the search bar "Terminal" and click the Terminal utility
>   - it should be a black box icon looking thing.
>
> (2)  Type in "sudo killall coreaudiod" into the Terminal black box thingy that pops up.
>
> (3) It'll automatically show a warning sign and tell you to enter your
>   computers password.  (To be honest, I didnt know what the warning sign
>   meant.  But I was desperate to try anything after searching close to
>   an hour for an answer to this problem.)
>
> (4) Type in your computer
>   password.
>
> (5) Restart the google hangout application by exiting out
>   and opening it again.
>
> (6) Try calling someone again and see if it
>   works!  Hope it does :/

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/hangouts/s7aHXZChsaM/gWJ0QBVp4XUJ

Comment: I was skeptical because neither my girlfriend or I could hear each other, but when we *both* followed these instructions, it worked great. Worth noting: my Bluetooth headset worked fine from the beginning, only the built-in mic didn't work.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I believe the problem was once I hit the block button when it asked for mic and there was literally no way for undoing it, except for your solution

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, it was the FaceTime app. I had to quit FaceTime, restart Chrome, and all was well.

Until... recently. Now, I get the camera working but the audio is still reported as being "hardware muted"...

**Edit:**

It seems that it's an issue in Chrome 37:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/vb-zDwFnARY

Google Support said that in the mean time, this work around might fix it:

Please try adjusting your mics' sample rate (on Macs, this would be via the "Audio MIDI Setup") to 48, 44.1, 32 or 16kHz.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the [Hangout Settings](http://support.google.com/plus/answer/1216370?hl=en) first.

Then check the properties of your recording devices and see if it will let you reduce the sound quality, sample rate, etc. The idea here is to make the sound data being transmitted over your Internet connections smaller, thus easier for a poor connection to handle. Depending on you OS & hardware, there may be few settings which can be adjusted. On the other hand, some high end sound devices allow a lot of customization.

Sorry this answer is vague, but you didn't give us much detail to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had this problem too, but it turned out that google hangout needed my mic to be much more sensitive. I maxed the input sensitivity in the system settings (-> sound -> input) and now people on the other side can hear me!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, all that needs to be done is to disable mic enhancements, assuming that you have configured your Hangouts to use correct input and output audio devices. So lets get on with it.

On Windows system go to Control Panel, Sound. Then click on Recording tab, highlight your microphone and click Properties. You should see something like this:

[image: mic no sound in google hangouts]

Uncheck the ‘Enable audio enhancements’ hit Apply or just OK and you should be good to go.

I've published this solution on my blog:
http://www.dolejarz.com/no-sound-in-google-hangouts/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please include in your answer the relevant content from the linked page? This ensures that your answer remains helpful even if the linked page changes or the link breaks.

Comment: [It is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Additionally you should read [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and our guidelines on [self-promotion](http://superuser.com/help/promotion).  Specifically your answers should be self-contained, complete and not rely entirely on a link that may go dead in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents, this may be a Chome issue as well. My microphone was blocked for the Google Hangouts in the `Chrome` settings and needed to delete from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I clicked the lock to the left of the link when you're on google meet. Go to site settings. Then under microphone, switch ask to allow. Then restart chrome and it should work. Hope this helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolve Camera and microphone always turning off after few seconds I turned it ON

Window 10
Window Start Button >>>> Setting >>>>> Privacy >>>> Camera

Make sure Allow apps to access your Camera ans Allow desktop apps to access your camera is ON and Google Chome is in the list below it

Window Start Button >>>> Setting >>>>> Privacy >>>> Microphone

Make sure Allow apps to access your Microphone and Allow desktop apps to access your Microphone is ON and Google Chome is in the list below it

Answer (score -1):

I experience this problem periodically. I have to completely quit Chrome and start it again to get the microphone working.